# LongListSelector SelectionChanged won't called

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have this Template in `LongListSelector`:

```
<local:SearchTemplateSelector.LoadMoreTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Load more..." FontSize="30" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="0" 
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,35"/>
                                    <Rectangle Height="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="White" Grid.Row="1" Opacity="0.3"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:SearchTemplateSelector.LoadMoreTemplate>
```

This is the `LongListSelector`:

```
    <Controls:LongListSelector x:Name="searchList" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Background="Black" SelectionChanged="DidPressSelectSearchList" 
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" KeyDown="UserPressEnterKeyBoard" Grid.Row="1">
        <Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:SearchTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

And i have a problem that when i press this row in the list so the `DidPressSelectSearchList` called only when i press the `TextBlock` and not trigger if i press another place on the Row.

Any idea how to fix it?

Edit i try this:

```
<local:SearchTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
```

And it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the problem like yours ([*LongListSelector* error](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52656761/LongListSelector%20error/LongListSelector%20error.png)).

> I tried to figure out how to
>   solve it, but I didn't find the solution. I added the picture to
>   describe the problem more clearly. The blue box (on the picture) is
>   the area when tap event raise, the red box is the area when nothing
>   happen, when you tapped there. When I use a Listbox instead of using a
>   LongListSelector all works normally as expected.

But I tried that **Silver Solver** advised and it is really works for me.
I think, you simple made a mistake.

Notice this property *Background="Transparent"* inside `<Grid>` element, which placed inside `<DataTemplate>` and `<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>` consistently (code placed below).

I think you had the problem, because you should set `<Grid>` element for the `<Controls:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>` and then set *Background="Transparent"* to the `<Grid>` element. Then you could put inside `<Grid>` element anything you like. Also you can add event `Tap="Grid_Tap"`for the `<Grid>` element, so it will triggered whenever you tap inside `<Grid>` element area.

This is my sample of code, try it:

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector                    
                x:Name="LongListMultiSelector" 
                Margin="0,0,0,0"  
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"                     
                SelectionChanged="SelectionChanged"
                IsSelectionEnabledChanged="IsSelectionEnabledChanged"                              
                EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="False" 
                >
                <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                            
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,17" 
                              Tap="Grid_Tap"                                       
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  
                              Background="Transparent">                                     
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Text}"
                                        TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                                        Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"                                            
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"                                          
                                        />                                        
                        </Grid>                            
                    </DataTemplate> 
                </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

P.S. **Silver Solver** thank you very much, sorry but I can't increase you reputation due to the small reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your root element in the ItemTemplate has a background set, else it will not register clicks.

```
<DataTemplate>
            <local:SearchTemplateSelector Background="Transparent"...
```

If your Selector does not have a Background property, just wrap it in a Grid.